# Remove all TextWatchers from an EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

i'm trying to add some TextWatchers on a EditText, but I should to remove all of them when I need it.

```
...

@BindView(R.id.widget_search_edittext)
MaterialEditText mEditText;

private List<TextWatcher> textWatcherList;

...

public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
    textWatcherList.add(watcher);
    mEditText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
}

public void removeAllTextChangedListeners() {
    for (TextWatcher watcher : textWatcherList) {
        mEditText.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
    }
    textWatcherList.clear();
}
```

but that didn't work, any ideias?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you override `equals()` in the extended TextWather Class. Because watcher stored in arrayList abd removed by calling `arraylist.indexOf(watcher)` that depend on equals function.

```
public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
    if (mListeners == null) {
        mListeners = new ArrayList<TextWatcher>();
    }
    mListeners.add(watcher);
}
/**
 * Removes the specified TextWatcher from the list of those whose
 * methods are called
 * whenever this TextView's text changes.
 */
public void removeTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
    if (mListeners != null) {
        int i = mListeners.indexOf(watcher);
        if (i >= 0) {
            mListeners.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

look how textView remove Watcher internally

Comment: When I try to remove the watcher the equals its never called

Comment: I just tryied to put an break point in there to test it. But the debugger never reach it.     @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof MyMaskWatcher) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }